# Shortcut Key to Return to Usage position

Tags: android, android-studio

Using Android Studio on a Windows platform, when my cursor is on a class or method, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to go to the declaration of a class or method to view the definition.

What is the shortcut key that will return me to the point of origin (where the class/method was referenced)?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, to *Navigate back/forward*, use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>

[IntelliJ Default keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse there is a shortcut for this (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>). I haven't found a shortcut for Android Studio that does the same, so I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead. It will return the cursor/focus to the code where I last edited something. Before I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on a method or class I press space then backspace somewhere near the code, so the cursor can return there when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find either so I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to see the definition. It's not the best view but better then spend time trying to figure out where you were in the code.

Comment: Ctrl+Q shows the details about definition inline. Not sure if that is what you are looking for. Also, I use it on Flutter projects. Hope it will be the same with other type of Android projects also.